# On android Cordova 2.1 app, ajax request always being interrupted and returns HTML-page with offer to update Browser (Dolphin HD)

Tags: android, cordova, dolphin-browser

I have a really weird behaviour on android app (Cordova 2.1).

I simple use code like that:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: this.serverUrl,
        data:data,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 3000, // in milliseconds
        success: function(data) {
            //never gets here...
        },
        error: function(request, status, err) {
            //always gets here
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    });
```

request.responseText always contains html-page with this content: http://dimalezhnev.ru/assets/tmp/html.txt (I placed the output in this file).

I draw a picture in my mind that browser while doing ajax request drop it and returns response with that html - forces user to update the browser in agressive style.

How to prevent it? I just can't imagine why is this happening now.

Comment: That is weird. What version of Dolphin HD are you using?

Comment: I dont use any. Cordova could use one? Or is this kind of mobile virus?

Comment: That was some program changed my .htaccess files on server. We are trying to find how they did it.

But it's clear that Cordova is not the source of problem.

Comment: Okay, cool. Hope you get your server sorted. And no, Cordova does not use Dolphin HD.